# JQuery Smooth Div Scroll can not work with dynamic data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use JQuery Smooth Div Scroll. In html

```
<div id="makeMeScrollable">
    <div class="queuenum">10</div>
    <div class="queuenum">20</div>
    <div class="queuenum">30</div>
    <div class="queuenum">40</div>
    <div class="queuenum">50</div>
    <div class="queuenum">60</div>
    <div class="queuenum">70</div>
    <div class="queuenum">80</div>
    <div ng-show="ishow" class="queuenum">90</div>
    <div class="queuenum">10</div>
    <div class="queuenum">20</div>
    <div class="queuenum">21</div>
    <div class="queuenum">12</div>
    <div class="queuenum">13</div>
    <div class="queuenum">14</div>
    <div class="queuenum">15</div>
    <div class="queuenum">17</div>
    <div class="queuenum">19</div>
    <div class="queuenum">14</div>
    <div class="queuenum">88</div>
    </div>
```

It work well.
But I load dynamic data by angularjs. It not work

```
<div id="makeMeScrollable" ng-repeat="order in currentlist1" class="row">           
<div class="queuenum">{{order.queue}}</div>         
</div>
```

Please help me.

Comment: Can you please share the code where you activate the JQuery smooth div scrolling?

Comment: Shouldn't your `ng-repeat` be on the queuenum div? After all that is what is repeating...

Comment: I used other way. Append div to  #makeMeScrollable. After that call contructor of smoothDivScroll. But it not work